# How can I fix "This database cannot be imported" error in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a program in C# that uses SQL database. I have the option to create an account and store the user's information in the database. If I create a new account it works and when I want to view the database content it gives me this error:

> This database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL Server version or an unsupported compatibility.

Here is the code I wrote for creating a new user.

```
try
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxEmail.Text.ToString()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxFirstName.Text.ToString()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxLastName.Text.ToString()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxPassword.Text.ToString()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxUsername.Text.ToString()))
    {
        textBoxEmail.Text = " ";
        textBoxFirstName.Text = " ";
        textBoxLastName.Text = " ";
        textBoxPassword.Text = " ";
        textBoxUsername.Text = " ";
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid value", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {

        using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Students(username, first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (@user, @first, @last, @email, @pass)", _conn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE username=@user", _conn))
            {
                _conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", this.textBoxUsername.Text.ToString().Trim());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username already exists, please use another one", "Username exists", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        _conn.Close();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                rd.Close();
                _conn.Close();
            }
            _conn.Open();
            _cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", this.textBoxUsername.Text.ToString().Trim());
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", this.textBoxFirstName.Text.ToString().Trim());
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", this.textBoxLastName.Text.ToString().Trim());
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", this.textBoxEmail.Text.ToString().Trim());
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", this.textBoxPassword.Text.ToString().Trim());
            _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _conn.Close();
        }
        textBoxEmail.Text = " ";
        textBoxFirstName.Text = " ";
        textBoxLastName.Text = " ";
        textBoxPassword.Text = " ";
        textBoxUsername.Text = " ";
        DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("User created succesfully\nDo you want to login?", "User created", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            this.Hide();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    textBoxEmail.Text = " ";
    textBoxFirstName.Text = " ";
    textBoxLastName.Text = " ";
    textBoxPassword.Text = " ";
    textBoxUsername.Text = " ";
    MessageBox.Show("Error:\n" + ex, "Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

And please tell me if there is another way to view the SQL database content.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3CFQ.png) when I hit refresh it gives me that error.

Comment: Where did you get the database file from?

Comment: I created the database file in Visual Studio.

Comment: Where does the Exception occure?

Comment: The exception occures when I try to visualize the database and refresh it.

Comment: OK, then what *kind* of database is it? How did you create it?

Comment: It it an SQL Local database and I created it using `Project\Add New Item\Service-Based Database` in Visual Studio.

Comment: _"please tell me if there is another way to view the SQL database content."_ - please tell us how you're trying to view it currently!

Comment: I am trying to view it through Visual Studio.

Comment: "service-based database" creates a SQL Server database. If you try to open that using Compact Edition client, it will fail. Can you verify if this is what you're doing? To be clear, to use a .mdf file you get from "service-based database", you need the appropriate SQL Server installed and running.

Comment: DO NOT use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). And storing passwords as plain-text is a terrible idea as well.